# What is the correct Syntax for "OR" condition inside "IF".?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Have an if condition like below

```
if ((listbox != "lhs") || (listbox != "prevnext"))
```

This is failing even when listbox is "lhs" or "prevnext" string.

Tried even below syntax but its failing

```
if ((listbox != "lhs" || listbox != "prevnext"))
```

Not sure of correct syntax for above condition.

Comment: Both the syntax are correct. There may be a logical error.

Comment: It should fail when listbox is lhs or prevnex, it will only trigger when it's something else.

Comment: you should just use == instead of != and it will work.

Comment: @MathijsSegers  actually && instead of || - but depends what you want **true** to mean

Comment: Upon which condition do you want to enter the "if" or the "else" ? As stated in many answers and comments, your current condition will always evaluate to true cause one of the 2 conditions (or even both) will always be `true`, there is no way for them to both be `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (!(listbox == 'lhs' || listbox == 'prevnext')) {
```

or

```
if (listbox   != 'lhs' || listbox != 'prevnext') {
```

Comment: the second one is the same as the original question? the first one is right

Comment: @Light...Yes, second one does not work but Thanks for first one, It works.

Comment: @KrankyCode: For future reference, this is known as DeMorgan's theorem, which states that `!(A || B)` is the same as `!A && !B` and `!( A && B)` is the same as `!A || !B`. Therefore, what you want is `!A && !B` instead of `!A || !B`. This bit of boolean algebra is used in digital electronics design to simplify circuits or convert between logic high and logic low circuits. But it occurs so often in programming that programmers should also learn this.

Comment: @slebetman thanks for detail explaination on theorem which i had learned long back ago...

Comment: @RakeshSadhula: Yeah, but you have forgotten :) Otherwise you wouldn't be wondering why your `if` statement didn't work

Answer (score 6):

```
if ((listbox != "lhs") || (listbox != "prevnext"))
```

This statement will always be true - because listbox will never equal both values

sorry I may have confused some people by not posting an answer ... @Light has **a** solution (the first snippet, the second snippet is clearly identical to the question without inner brackets)

some people just need that facepalm moment to realise the answer themselves

I'd use

```
if ((listbox != "lhs") && (listbox != "prevnext"))
```

if listbox="fred" ...

```
if (("fred" != "lhs") && ("fred" != "prevnext"))
           true       &&        true              result = true
```

if listbox="lhs" ...

```
if (("lhs" != "lhs") && ("lhs" != "prevnext"))
           false     &&        true              result = false
```

if listbox="prevnext" ...

```
if (("lhs" != "lhs") && ("lhs" != "prevnext"))
           true      &&        false             result = false
```

looks right to me

Comment: I'm not sure what the volatility is about with this answer - it's not wrong.

Comment: @Jaromanda... That does not work for my requirement as i do not want code to execute on either conditions i.e if listbox == "lhs" OR listbox == "prevnext"... so "&&" will not work

Comment: @KrankyCode - !(a || b)  === (!a && !b) - check my edit for proof that it works - even made a fiddle to prove it - http://jsfiddle.net/f9tu9Lm1/

Comment: @JaromandaX I prefer `if(['lhs', 'prevnext'].indexOf(listbox) < 0){...`

Answer (score 0):

```
(listbox != "lhs" || listbox != "prevnext")
```

Always true - `listbox` can't be both `lhs` and `prevnext` at the same time, so it always IS NOT at least one of those values.

```
(listbox == "lhs" || listbox == "prevnext")
```

then:

```
listbox = 'lhs' // => true
listbox = 'prevnext' // => true
listbox = 'anything_else' // => false
```

True if `listbox` is `lhs` or `prevnext`.

```
(listbox != "lhs" && listbox != "prevnext")
```

then:

```
listbox = 'lhs' // => false
listbox = 'prevnext' // => false
listbox = 'anything_else' // => true
```

True if `listbox` is neither 'lhs', nor 'prevnext'.

```
(listbox == "lhs" && listbox == "prevnext")
```

For completeness - always false - listbox can't be equal to two values simultaneously.